# Scrollbox jquery is not working?

Tags: jquery

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>HTML marquee Tag</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

    <!-- Main CSS -->
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

    <!-- Responsive Framework -->
    <link href="responsive.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">        

    <!-- Fontawesome CSS -->
    <link href="font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">      
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.no-icons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <!-- scrollbox Script -->
    <script src="js/jquery.scrollbox.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">

        $('#demo').scrollbox({
           linear: true,
           step: 1,
           delay: 0,
           speed: 100
         });

      </script>    

      </head>
      <body>

      <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-6" id="demo">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">This text will scroll from bottom to up</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">This text will scroll from bottom to up</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">This text will scroll from bottom to up</a></li>
         </ul>
       </div>





     </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

This is my original code for scrollbox. Its not working yet..... 
At first, i attached the google apis, then scrollbox script imported from Github, then the function and the list with a div calling id="demo"

Comment: `$(function() {});` is shorthand for `$(document).ready(function() {});`

Comment: `<script src="js/jquery.scrollbox.js"></script>` should be included after jquery reference. Check console for errors. `.scrollbox is not a function...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make sure jQuery is loaded BEFORE the scrollbox.js
2. Use some of the CSS from the site of scrollbox

I added a few things like the CSS and more items to scroll.

Then I imported the scrollbox from the GitHub and changed the style

```
$('#demo').scrollbox({
   linear: true,
   step: 1,
   delay: 0,
   speed: 100
 });
```

and now it works

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/mwuLxfmv/)

Comment: The error log is showing : Uncaught TypeError: $(...).scrollbox is not a function

Answer (score 2):

Your `<script>` tags should be inverted, since scrollbox.js depends on jquery:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.scrollbox.js"></script>
```

Generally speaking, when something you expect does not happen, the first thing to check is the error log in Developer Tools (just press F12 in IE, FF or Chrome).

Comment: The error log is showing : Uncaught TypeError: $(...).scrollbox is not a function